# How do I get the user message that a Slack Botkit hears?

Tags: slack-api, botkit

Using Botkit, how can I get the message from the user that triggered what a Botkit hears? For example, a user says "Hello, how are you" and the bot hears "hello" as the keyword. I do I get the entire "Hello, how are you"?

Comment: Yes, you get the entire message + metadata. Check out the [example.](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/slack_bot.js)

Comment: Which part in the example?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else was wondering, you use **message.text** to access the message.